# How to Make a cross domain query with n1ql and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, couchbase, sql++

I know that n1ql use json for querys and I try to make one like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'my/url',
    data: {query: 'SELECT address FROM restaurant WHERE docType\=\'user\''},
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,

    success: function(rtndata) {
        console.log(rtndata.resultset);
    },

    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Was an error");
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("Status: " + status);
        console.dir(xhr);
    },
});
```

I need to use ajax for refreshing only a graph on my website that is using json because my DB is in another domain. In the past I used php but right now I'm using play framwork for java on the server side.

Update:
When I do that, the server always responds with:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (query, line 0)
```

Comment: There are a bunch of troubleshooting steps you can do right away. For starters, have you tried using Fiddler to debug? What happened? I have not reviewed the cb api documentation recently, but you might also check examples there to ensure yours matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data element to:

data: {query: 'SELECT address FROM restaurant WHERE docType="user"'},